# Why debugger shows that variable is empty

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsurlrequest

I have implemented url request to server and going to work with received JSON. 
But there is strange thing I cant explain.

My ViewController class:

```
import UIKit

class TopRatedViewController: UIViewController {

    var importedRates: NSArray = []
    var successfullyConnected: Bool = true


    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        print(importedRates)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //MARK: Connection to web service
        let urlString: String = "http://alma.com/get.php"

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                self.successfullyConnected = false
            }else {
                var jsonresult = NSArray()
                do {
                    jsonresult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
                        self.importedRates = jsonresult
                } catch _ {
                    print("error loading rates")
                }
            }
        })

        task.resume()
        print(importedRates)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

So if I run my application print(importedRates) command prints empty array. And in debug window I see that there is nothing in it.

BUT. if I click on button which then is supposed to print this variable - it successfully prints an array with 40 elements.
Can anybody explain why it is working like this?

I was expecting that this variable should be populated with data in viewdidload method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting an asynchronous call in `viewDidLoad` that sets `self.importedRates = jsonresult` on completion.

Everything in the `completionHandler` is executed with a very high probability after `print(importedRates)`, to be more precise: At the time, the network request comes back (depending on your network and the request, a few microseconds to several minutes)

That is why the button press works: By the time you push the button, the request did finish and populate the array correctly.

Using synchronous requests on the main thread is highly discouraged. This might lead to your app being unresponsive (because all user input in handled on the main thread and cannot proceed as long as the synchornous call is waiting for a response.

Rather, if the data you expect arrives, call a method of the view controller from within the `completionHandler` that uses the now-set property in the way you want it to be used. For example, if you were trying to populate a `self.tableView : UITableView!`:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                self.successfullyConnected = false
            }else {
                var jsonresult = NSArray()
                do {
                    jsonresult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.importedRates = jsonresult
                        self.tableView.reloadData() // look here
 }
                } catch _ {
                    print("error loading rates")
                }
            }
        })

        task.resume()
```

Comment: it makes sense. thank you. is there a way to create non asynchronous call? :) to have all comands executed one after another

Comment: @Almazini, I updated my answer.

Comment: @SmokeDispanser have you added only one row or there are more changes? For me it is not working for some reason. Is there a way to handle CompletionHandler?

Comment: That is meant to be an example. You have to adapt it to your needs. I only called one method on `self.tableView`.

Comment: well it is similar to what I need actually. I am doing few transformations of array and then reloading tableview. but when application loads table is empty.

Comment: Oh, you need to dispatch that to the main thread, as the completionHandler runs in the network thread. I will edit my answer as soon as I am returning home.

Comment: There you go, OP:)

Comment: yes it works perfectly! thank you!

Comment: @SmokeDispanser your solution works fine for pulling data into a table. I was trying to implement such logic: connect to server, download data into coredata, load data into a table from coredata. if there are issues with downloading data and updating coredata - so just simply load from coredata. What is the best way of getting status of downloading data process? There is successfullyConnected variable for that in my example BUT because of asynchronous request it always has initial value(false) when I try to check it and only then it changes to true(after data is downloaded successfully)

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.